# isotope columnshift doesn't work when child is trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I am trying to use this layout: [masonry column shift](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/masonry-column-shift.html)

This works for me when I click the main item:

```
$container.find('.wrapper').click(function(){
        $(this).css({ height: "+=100" });
        // note that element is passed in, not jQuery object
        $container.isotope( 'shiftColumnOfItem', this );
});
```

and this is what I want (trigger the size change when clicking a child):

```
$container.find('.wrapper li').click(function(){
        var closestwrapper = $(this).closest('.wrapper');
        closestwrapper.css({ height: "+=100" });
        // note that element is passed in, not jQuery object
        $container.isotope( 'shiftColumnOfItem', this );
});
```

The size changes but it wont shift the column. I also tried using `closestwrapper` instead of `this`.

On the demo page there is a comment that I don't understand:

```
// note that element is passed in, not jQuery object
```

Comment: try with .parent() instead of closest

Comment: `this` would be in the second example .wrapper li, so I don't think you want to shidt that. Try to user another selector for call the .wrapper at this place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"On the demo page there is a comment that I don't understand:"*
>
> `// note that element is passed in, not jQuery object`

A DOM element is the object representing the element on the page. A jQuery object is an object constructed by the jQuery library, which usually contains one or more DOM elements.

In your first `isotope()` call, you're passing `this`, which in that case is a DOM element.

But in the second version, if you try to pass `closestwrapper`, you're passing a jQuery object that contains the DOM element. So what you need is to extract the DOM element from the jQuery object.

jQuery stores the DOM Elements at zero-based numeric indices, so you can use the typical Object member operator to get the DOM element.

```
// -----------------------------------------------------v
$container.isotope( 'shiftColumnOfItem', closestwrapper[0] );
```